# Eclipse and Cassandra

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra, git-bash

I've searched various websites for instructions on how to link 'Cassandra' and 'Eclipse' and followed directions to the last detail in several sites. For some reason, while using Git Bash, I cant get through the 'ant build', via instruction in said mentioned locations across the web.

In some location's its easy, just make sure you have;
     1. Apache Cassandra source
     2. Apache Ant
     3. Git

So, yeah I've downloaded all the above, tried the same directory, different directories, etc., although still unable to get past the middle step of 'ant build'.

Here are a few websites I've used to muddle through setting up the Src code for both utilities, 'Eclipse' and 'Cassandra'.

http://uisurumadushanka89.blogspot.com/2012/02/apache-cassandra-how-to-setup-source.html
and
http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInEclipse

both resulting in an immediate halt at the 'ant build'.

any insights are information is greatly appreciated.

Thank-you,
Ryan

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: At least the error messages would be helpful, if there are any.

Comment: Here's a screen shot of the error, ![Eclipse/Cassandra Error](img src="https://ws.elance.com/php/files/main/download.php?crypted=Y3R4JTNEd3Nfc2hhcmVkJTI2ZmlkJTNENTMxNTA1NDElMjZyaWQlM0QtMSUyNnBpZCUzRDMzMjc2NDQ2")

Comment: Please edit post and add screen inside. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91716/how-to-upload-screenshots

Comment: my bad on the screenshot add...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ant isn't on your path. Try running it with an absolute path to wherever you installed it, something like:

```
cd /C/CassandraSRC/cassandra
/C/install/path/ant build
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The problem is while you have ant installed, the system doesn't know where to find it, so you have to give it the full path to the ant binary in order to be able to execute it. Once you've found it, you can add it to your $PATH environment variable. There are numerous tutorials online about how to do that.